# Positional argument missing error in scipy optimize

Tags: scipy, scipy-optimize

I wanted to get a maximum estimate for the following function in mu and sigma using scipy where s is defined as the sample

`s = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 100)`

```
def f(mu, sigma):
  x = norm.pdf(s,mu,sigma)
  x = np.prod(x)
  x = np.log(x)
  return x
```

I've tried

```
x0 = [0,1]


bounds = [(-5,5),(-5,5)]

print(optimize.minimize(f, x0, method='SLSQP', bounds=bounds))
```

but keep getting the error:

> f() missing 1 required positional argument: 'sigma'

I'm not sure what's going on here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the arguments to `f` as a vector:

```py
def f(z):
  mu, sigma = z
  x = norm.pdf(s,mu,sigma)
  x = np.prod(x)
  x = np.log(x)
  return x
```

Comment: This worked, thank you!

Comment: Glad it did, please approve the answer if the topic is closed. @user135520